# What is the complete beginner's road map for learning Web 3.0 Decentralized applications and writing smart contracts?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs, decentralization

As a front end developer (using React.js), I want to understand blockchain so that I may create decentralised applications (dapps), NFT marketplaces, and solidity contracts. However, I'm not familiar with the roadmap.

Comment: Try googling complete beginner's road map for learning Web 3.0 Decentralized applications... You'll find many guides...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already experienced start by reading about eth and solidity from official docs, you will get detailed roadmaps, lectures and guided projects through many options like these. ( There will be many better options these was my choices )

### YOUTUBE

- Smart contract programmer
- Eat the blocks
- Dapp university

### EXPERIENCES BY GUIDED PROJECTS

- Buildspace.io
- Ethernaut.dao
- Cryptozombies
- learnweb3.io

### ROADMAP

- Build a base in solidity and diffrent tools
- Consider some guided projects
- Make your own new features in those projects
- Build something from scratch

Comment: Yes I'm learning solidity from cryptozombies. Best platform for a beginner

Comment: Also check the buildspace its a great platform.